# What is the clear difference of a Ancestor Key and a Parent Key?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

What is the clear difference of a Ancestor Key and a Parent Key?

Is it basically the same? **How does it differently affect a get() method and a `Query` method?**

From the GAE `KeyFactory` class, we can only see the `Key` parent and no such ancestor `Key`.

```
public static Key createKey(Key parent, String kind, String name) {
    return createKey(parent, kind, name, (AppIdNamespace)null);
}
```

Then use the key like this:

```
Entity e = new Entity(key); // key may include a parent Key
```

In a typical query, like in a guestbook app. We can make a Key as an ancestor, so we can have different guestbooks to which Entities could be saved like:

```
Key guestbookKey = KeyFactory.createKey("Guestbook", guestbookName);
Query q = new Query(kind, guestbookKey); // guestbookKey = ancestor
```

**So what is the difference of a Parent and Ancestor**, are they basically the same thing without any difference, the same thing with just different notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Parent` means an **immediate** parent.  An `Ancestor` is a more general term, encompassing immediate parents, parents of parents, parents of parents of parents, and so forth -- exactly the same use as in English.

An "entity group", the kind on which you can ask for an atomic transaction, need to be made up of entities with a common **ancestor** -- they don't need to all have the same (immediate) **parent**, but their lines of descent do need to meet at one common **ancestor** some way "up the line" (not necessarily the same number of steps for all entities involved).

When you `createKey` based on a `parent` key, **that** parent key may in turn have been made with its own parent -- and if that is so, then the parent's parent is not itself the parent of what you're creating now, but, it **is** an ancestor thereof.

Comment: Nice explanation. So when doing the above guestbook query, I can put the key of the immediate parent, the the result will be just the Entities of that parent key I just put. However if I put a more "older" ancestor it would return more entities?

Comment: @xybrek, yes, I believe that would be the case (it's how ancestor queries work in Python's `ndb` -- I'm less familiar with the Java equivalent but I believe the functionality is the same, just packaged differently).